# How to run non-dependent sibling tasks sequentially?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

Let's suppose I have a dag with 4 tasks, and the structure would be more or less like this if we only care about the order in which they are run:

```
t1.set_downstream(t2)
t2.set_downstream(t3)
t3.set_downstream(t4)
```

This let's me run the tasks sequentially t1 -> t2 -> t3 -> t4

My issue is, I want them to run in the above sequence, but I want t4 to ignore if and only if t3 fails.

I.e: the graph would look like this if we only care about dependencies

```
t1.set_downstream(t2)
t2.set_downstream(t3)
t2.set_downstream(t4)
```

What can I do to have both scenarios?
My current option is to set the trigger rule of t4 to `all_done`, however, I don't want it to run if t1 or t2 fails.

Any ideas? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [BranchOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/branch/index.html#airflow.operators.branch.BaseBranchOperator) to add the logic you are looking for. Or even create your own SkipOperator based on [SkipMixin](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/skipmixin/index.html#airflow.models.skipmixin.SkipMixin).

Comment: These work! I was just about to write, I ended up solving this by using the `ShortCircuitOperator` out of the `operators.python` module. Browsed over your options as well!